# wp_enqueue_style giving error with custom_style.php in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have issue in wp_enqueue_style, when i enqueue 'custom_style.php' in wp_enqueue_style in plugin file then wp displaying 500 error, but when i enqueue same process in theme then it works properly.

Please check my code

```
In **plugin file** 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
function theme_name_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'customstyle', plugins_url('css/custom_style.php', __FILE__));
}
**custom_style.php**

header("Content-type: text/css");

global $wpdb;

$bgcolor=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT bgcolor FROM tablename where id=$id");

?>
.form-box{
    background-color: <?php echo $bgcolor; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Bro tell me please why you enqueue file from your theme .... you must put this file in your plugin

Comment: Because in my plugin, multiple form listed in backend and every form has shortcode, when i put that shortcode in any page then form will be display in popup with all related css. So i developed one style.php file which is fetch all data by form id and set css in popup. most of paid theme follow this type of scenario.

Comment: ok can you do one more thing .... open your site in browser and do this (ctrl+u) and see in code that your file exits in there

Comment: yes myfile exists and when i click url then it will display 500 error. just click this link http://naturalab.ommunedemo.com/ and then press ctrl+u and find 'natura_frontpopup-css'.

Comment: i find your "custom_style.php" file but it does not exists there !!!!!!!

Comment: @deemi, find please 'formpreview_popup.php', its big name that's why i mentioned small filename.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

To

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Here is complete solution

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_register_style('your_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)).'css/custom_style.php');
    wp_enqueue_style('your_css');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @deemi,
 But i already change this code but its not work.

Comment: @PHPSmart Please make sure that your code is correct before posting so that no one wastes their time answering irrelevant info

Comment: @Pieter Goosen, Sorry for wrong sentence, i already check this code but its not work.